# IDEA dosen't highlight .graphql files with project schema

Tags: java, intellij-idea, graphql

I am working on a project that involves a GraphQL schema with .graphqls files stored in a separate directory. Additionally, I have a Java Maven module where I keep the .graphql queries within the resources directory. Previously, my IDEA used to highlight objects, functions, and other elements within these queries. However, the highlighting feature is no longer functioning properly, although the general GraphQL highlighting still works. I have installed the GraphQL plugin, and all functions in the schema files are functioning correctly. How can I resolve this issue?

Mark graphql schema as resources, check idea settings for file type, invalidate caches, reinstall project.

Answer (score 0):

If you are storing your GraphQL schemas and queries in separate modules, you'll have to link them via GraphQL Plugin configuration (graphql.config.yml) as explained [here](https://github.com/JetBrains/js-graphql-intellij-plugin#basic-configuration).

Hope this helps!